# Stop filezilla server from using port 22

Tags: windows, ssh, ftp, filezilla

I'm using Windows Server 2012r2, I've installed filezilla ftp server on it which should use port 21, as specified by the setting, however it also seems to be using port 22.

I checked this by command line 'netstat -anb' < this command tell you which ports are being used by which services.

My developer need ssh access, filezilla doesn't come with ssh it uses tls/ssl instead and ssh isn't native to Windows. So I installed 'freesshd' however this won't run because the ssh port is already in use by filezilla.

Is there anyway for me to stop filezilla using port 22 only, I still need it to run for my ftp port 21 and ftps port 990?

Comment: I've been running FileZilla for seven or more years, along with sshd. I've never seen a conflict. Off topic.

Comment: Lucky you, I keep getting "the specified address is already in use" When I try to run sshd.http://www.freesshd.com/index.php?ctt=forum&action=view&topic=1138038588 This link proved to be pretty useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I done - if anyone ever has this problem.

I completely stopped filezilla service on windows services as I already knew this was the cause using the command 'netstat -anb' as mentioned above.

I then restarted the freesshd service, checked 'netstat -anb' to see it was using port 22 was using freesshd. Once this was confirmed I started Filezilla again.

I'm not sure if this is a long term solution but it's working for now